# Transition affects the background image

Tags: html, css

When I hover on div then the background image also moves.If I remove this line
  `transition:transform 0.2s;` then
background image does not move towards right direction.Why this is happening?
I have attatched the codepen link here:
https://codepen.io/SowmiyaPachiappan/pen/RwbpjvN

Please Help me. How to resolve it?

```css
section {
  padding: 10rem 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(126, 213, 111, 0.8), rgba(40, 180, 133, 0.8)), url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eQBu3UBQby0/maxresdefault.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-6deg);
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
  color: #777;
}

section>* {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(6deg);
  transform: skewY(6deg);
}

.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
}

row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.col-1-of-4 {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
}

.feature-box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
}

.feature-box:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-of-4">
      <div class="feature-box">
        <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">Explore the world</h3>
        <p class="feature-box__text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus optio laborum
        </p>
        <div>
        </div>

      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Does not seem to be moving, seems like the browsers needs to re-render parts of the page when the feature-box is moving. There are alot of transforms in play, so it's to be expected. Maybe you should try to make the background-image the right shape in the first place, so you won't need to transform: skewY for the background nor the feature-box?

Comment: How to solve this using code?

Comment: I don't see any moving as well (Firefox on Win10). Which browser on which platform does this issue occur?

Comment: It occurs in chrome on win 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the issue in my browser, but maybe this helps.

I decouple the background (incl. skew) and the text-content by introdicing a dedicated `div.background`.

```css
section {
  padding: 10rem 0;
  color: #777;
  position: relative;
}

section>.background,
section>.background:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

section>.background {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-6deg);
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}

section>.background:after {
  content: '';
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(126, 213, 111, 0.8), rgba(40, 180, 133, 0.8)), url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eQBu3UBQby0/maxresdefault.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(6deg);
  transform: skewY(6deg);
}

.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
}

row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.col-1-of-4 {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
}

.feature-box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, transform 0.2s;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.feature-box:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-of-4">
      <div class="feature-box">
        <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">Explore the world</h3>
        <p class="feature-box__text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus optio laborum
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```